# how to Pass Parameters to php page without having to load it

Tags: php, mysql, html, google-maps

how can i pass parameters from an html page(map.html) to a php(createxml.php) without having to open the php page? Im incorporating googlemaps in html page(map.html) so i want the users to enter data on a form on the html page which will be sent to php(createxml.php) which in turn will connect to mySQL DB and create an xml format of the response the html page uses this xml output to create positions on the map since it contains longitude and latitude.
I have used the following code in the heading of the php page(createxml), but it shows the contents of php file for a brief moment redirecting me to map.html
Thanks for your time, i can post all the code if needed.

```
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost/map.html/">
```

Comment: Do you want to do a php redirect or use AJAX to never leave the page in the first place?

Comment: I have never used AJAX, i m familiar with php only.its exactly what i want, not leave the page but pass parameters to the php page which will create the xml output needed by my html having google map api to create the position

Comment: can't you just include() createxml.php in  map.html ?

Comment: the issue is that the output of createxml.php is an xml file, i only want the parameters passed to the php while staying in map.html so map.html can later check the output of createxml.php and update the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple with AJAX, using jQuery you don't have to know much about it :)
So simply import the latest [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/).

Then you have your form:

```
<form id="my_form">
<input type="text" name="param1" />
<input type="text" name="param2" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_stuff" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and somewhere beneath that, you just paste this tiny javascript-function, which handles the submit of the form:

```
<script>
  $('#my_form').submit(function(){
    var post_params = $('#my_form').serialize();
    $('#waiting').show();
    $.post('the_page_you_are_on.php', post_params, function(data) {
      $('#waiting').hide();
      return false;
    })
  });
</script>
```

(The element (div, p...) with the id "waiting" could e.g. contain one of those fancy ajax loading images, but is not neccessary! :) If you want one to be shown, find one via google, set it as the background image of the #waiting-element and set its display to none (CSS)).

The function itself just calls the page you're on and then you've got the form variables in your post-array, so the top of your page could look something like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
  switch($_POST['action']) {
    case 'do_stuff' :
      $param1 = $_POST['param1'];
      $param2 = $_POST['param2'];

      //do some DB-stuff etc.
    break;
  }
}

?>
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's a terrible idea, but because you don't want to use AJAX you could put the PHP in a frame and reload just that portion.  Again, awful idea, but the closest you're going to get without using AJAX.

On a useful note though, AJAX is literally just one function in javascript.  It's not hard at all to learn.

Comment: Yeah. The rest is DOM manipulation. And it has nothing to do with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to pass parameters to a PHP page from the web browser, there are other ways to do it beyond 'Ajax'.  Take a look at this page and view the source code (be sure to view the source of the included javascript file: http://hazlo.co/showlist.php?s=chrome&i=4e289d078b0f76b750000627&n=TODO

It uses an extremely basic method of changing the src of an image element, but passes information to the web server (PHP page) in the querystring of the image request.  In this example I actually care about the results, which are represented as an image, but it sounds like you are just trying to pass data to the server, so you can return a 1 pixel image if you like.  BTW, don't be fooled by the URL that is being used, a server rule is telling apache to process a specific PHP file when check it,GIF is requested.

You should play with it and use firebug or chrome's built in debugger to watch the requests that are being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any results from a PHP-script if you don't request it and process the output. If you dont't want to leave the current page, you **have to use AJAX**!

"but it shows the contents of php file for a brief moment" The reason is, that your browser first needs to load the entire page, then start the META-redirect. You don't need a redirect to load data from the server, but if you really want to, you should HTTP-headers for [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redirect).

Comment: looks like AJAX its time to learn abit of AJAX, thank you guys for your time.However if you know of a quick tutorial, ill be grateful! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys after hours of headache i finally found the solution! Basically i called my xmlproduce.php from inside my map.html, lemme explain so maybe will help others:

maps.html contained a googlmap API Javascript function which called my createxml.php called second.php

```
    GDownloadUrl("second.php", function(data) )
```

what i did was i tweaked this call to second.php by adding some parameters in the URL like:

```
     GDownloadUrl("second.php?strt="+ysdate+"/"+msdate+"/"+dsdate+"&end="+yedate+"  /"+medate+"/"+dedate+"&id="+ide, function(data)
```

which is sending the parameters needed by second.php, so after that i made a small html form which called the script of googlemap api on the same file(map.html) to pass the parameters from the form to the GDownloadUrl i mentioned above, the code of the form is :

```
    form method="get" action="">
        IMEI: <input type="text" id="id" name="id" size="25" /> <br />

        Start Date: <input type="text" id="ysdate" name="ysdate" size="4" value="2000" /> <input type="text" id="msdate" name="ysdate" size="1" /> <input type="text" id="dsdate" name="dsdate" size="1" /> <br/>
        End Date:   <input type="text" id="yedate" name="yedate" size="4" /> <input type="text" id="medate" name="ysdate" size="1" /> <input type="text" id="dedate" name="dedate" size="1" /> <br/>

                    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="load()" />
        </form>
```

afterwards i put extra constraints on the form for the values allowed.
Thanks everybody for the help, and you can always ask if somebody needs some clarification.